# Explanation about the property of KMP failure function

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

I am reading the [topcoder tutorial on KMP algorithm](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=stringSearching) and I fail to understand the following part of the text:

> Given a string (a quite long one), find all its proper suffixes that
>   are also prefixes of it. All we have to do is just to calculate the
>   "failure function" of the given string and using the information
>   stored in it to print the answer.

I know how to calculate the failure function and for a string `abacababa` I get the following array `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]`. The problem is that I can not figure out how it can help me to find

> all its proper suffixes that are also prefixes of it

which based on my understanding suppose to be `a` and `aba`.

Comment: do you have problem building the failure function or how to use it ?

Comment: @sasha from my question: `I know how to calculate the failure function ...  The problem is that I can not figure out how it can help me`

Comment: yes got your question. I have tried to explain broadly how you can find longest proper suffixes which are also prefixes while building this failure array/function.

Comment: @Phpdna really interesting , had not come cross using a trie to build automata. I looked up the wiki. Did not read much in detail but it also finds multiple matches in linear time and building a failure function also finds multiple matches in linear time. Would really like to know where this trie method has advantage over the regular.

Comment: @sash:You can also use a ternary trie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The longest proper suffix that is also a prefix is a prefix of length `p[n - 1]`. The next one is the longest suffix of this suffix which is also a prefix. It is exactly a prefix of length `p[p[n - 1] - 1]`. We keep repeating it until we get an empty prefix.

For example, for that `abacaba` string it goes this way:

1. The longest proper suffix which is also a prefix is `aba`(because `p[n - 1]` is `3`).
2. The longest proper suffix which is also a prefix of `aba` is `a`(because `p[2]` is `1`).
3. There is no such suffix for `a`(`p[0] = 0`), so we are done.

The code looks like this:

```
cur = p[n - 1]
while cur != 0:
     print(s[0 ... cur - 1])
     cur = p[cur - 1]
```

Comment: thank you. My brain is not working right now. Will reread the answer tomorrow.